# How to edit data in datagrid table row syncfusion with json api in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

[How to edit data in datagrid table row syncfusion with json api in flutter, How to edit data in datagrid table row syncfusion with json api in flutter,[How to edit data in datagrid table row syncfusion with json api in flutter, How to edit data in datagrid table row syncfusion with json api in flutter, How to edit data in datagrid table row syncfusion with json api in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTSoQ.jpg)

```dart
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';

class Employee {
  Employee(this.id, this.name, this.designation, this.salary);

  int id;
  String name;
  String designation;
  int salary;

  DataGridRow getDataGridRow() {
    return DataGridRow(cells: <DataGridCell>[
      DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'id', value: id),
      DataGridCell<String>(columnName: 'name', value: name),
      DataGridCell<String>(columnName: 'designation', value: designation),
      DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'salary', value: salary),
    ]);
  }
}
```

-->

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:editgrid/model/employee.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';

class EmployeeDataSource extends DataGridSource {
  EmployeeDataSource(this._employees) {
    dataGridRows = _employees
        .map<DataGridRow>((dataGridRow) => dataGridRow.getDataGridRow())
        .toList();
  }

  List<Employee> _employees = [];

  List<DataGridRow> dataGridRows = [];

  /// Helps to hold the new value of all editable widget.
  /// Based on the new value we will commit the new value into the corresponding
  /// [DataGridCell] on [onSubmitCell] method.
  dynamic newCellValue;

  /// Help to control the editable text in [TextField] widget.
  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => dataGridRows;

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter? buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((dataGridCell) {
      return Container(
          alignment: (dataGridCell.columnName == 'id' ||
                  dataGridCell.columnName == 'salary')
              ? Alignment.centerRight
              : Alignment.centerLeft,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          child: Text(
            dataGridCell.value.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ));
    }).toList());
  }

  @override
  void onCellSubmit(DataGridRow dataGridRow, RowColumnIndex rowColumnIndex,
      GridColumn column) {
    final dynamic oldValue = dataGridRow
            .getCells()
            .firstWhereOrNull((DataGridCell dataGridCell) =>
                dataGridCell.columnName == column.columnName)
            ?.value ??
        '';

    final int dataRowIndex = dataGridRows.indexOf(dataGridRow);

    if (newCellValue == null || oldValue == newCellValue) {
      return;
    }

    if (column.columnName == 'id') {
      dataGridRows[dataRowIndex].getCells()[rowColumnIndex.columnIndex] =
          DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'id', value: newCellValue);
      _employees[dataRowIndex].id = newCellValue as int;
    } else if (column.columnName == 'name') {
      dataGridRows[dataRowIndex].getCells()[rowColumnIndex.columnIndex] =
          DataGridCell<String>(columnName: 'name', value: newCellValue);
      _employees[dataRowIndex].name = newCellValue.toString();
    } else if (column.columnName == 'designation') {
      dataGridRows[dataRowIndex].getCells()[rowColumnIndex.columnIndex] =
          DataGridCell<String>(columnName: 'designation', value: newCellValue);
      _employees[dataRowIndex].designation = newCellValue.toString();
    } else {
      dataGridRows[dataRowIndex].getCells()[rowColumnIndex.columnIndex] =
          DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'salary', value: newCellValue);
      _employees[dataRowIndex].salary = newCellValue as int;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool canSubmitCell(DataGridRow dataGridRow, RowColumnIndex rowColumnIndex,
      GridColumn column) {
    // Return false, to retain in edit mode.
    return true; // or super.canSubmitCell(dataGridRow, rowColumnIndex, column);
  }

  @override
  Widget? buildEditWidget(DataGridRow dataGridRow,
      RowColumnIndex rowColumnIndex, GridColumn column, CellSubmit submitCell) {
    // Text going to display on editable widget
    final String displayText = dataGridRow
            .getCells()
            .firstWhereOrNull((DataGridCell dataGridCell) =>
                dataGridCell.columnName == column.columnName)
            ?.value
            ?.toString() ??
        '';

    // The new cell value must be reset.
    // To avoid committing the [DataGridCell] value that was previously edited
    // into the current non-modified [DataGridCell].
    newCellValue = null;

    final bool isNumericType =
        column.columnName == 'id' || column.columnName == 'salary';

    // Holds regular expression pattern based on the column type.
    final RegExp regExp = _getRegExp(isNumericType, column.columnName);

    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      alignment: isNumericType ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: TextField(
        autofocus: true,
        controller: editingController..text = displayText,
        textAlign: isNumericType ? TextAlign.right : TextAlign.left,
        autocorrect: false,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 16.0),
        ),
        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(regExp)
        ],
        keyboardType: isNumericType ? TextInputType.number : TextInputType.text,
        onChanged: (String value) {
          if (value.isNotEmpty) {
            if (isNumericType) {
              newCellValue = int.parse(value);
            } else {
              newCellValue = value;
            }
          } else {
            newCellValue = null;
          }
        },
        onSubmitted: (String value) {
          /// Call [CellSubmit] callback to fire the canSubmitCell and
          /// onCellSubmit to commit the new value in single place.
          submitCell();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  RegExp _getRegExp(bool isNumericKeyBoard, String columnName) {
    return isNumericKeyBoard ? RegExp('[0-9]') : RegExp('[a-zA-Z ]');
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';
import 'datasource/employee_datasource.dart';
import 'model/employee.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'SfDataGrid Editing'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late EmployeeDataSource _employeeDataSource;
  List<Employee> _employees = <Employee>[];
  late DataGridController _dataGridController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _employees = getEmployeeData();
    _employeeDataSource = EmployeeDataSource(_employees);
    _dataGridController = DataGridController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('SfDataGrid Editing'),
      ),
      body: SfDataGrid(
        source: _employeeDataSource,
        allowEditing: true,
        selectionMode: SelectionMode.single,
        navigationMode: GridNavigationMode.cell,
        columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill,
        controller: _dataGridController,
        columns: [
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'id',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Text(
                'ID',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'name',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Name',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'designation',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Designation',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'salary',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Text(
                'Salary',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Employee> getEmployeeData() {
    return [
      Employee(10001, 'James', 'Project Lead', 20000),
      Employee(10002, 'Kathryn', 'Manager', 30000),
      Employee(10003, 'Lara', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10004, 'Michael', 'Designer', 15000),
      Employee(10005, 'Martin', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10006, 'Newberry', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10007, 'Balnc', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10008, 'Perry', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10009, 'Gable', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10010, 'Grimes', 'Developer', 15000)
    ];
  }
}
```